# iOS: Using XCUIDevice().siriService to tap on button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xctest, ui-testing

I'm trying to to tap on button cell using UITestingUITests using siriService. For example:

I'm trying to open "Settings" and tap on "General":

[image]

I'm able to open the settings:

```
func testSettings() {
    XCUIDevice().siriService.activate(voiceRecognitionText: "Open Settings")
```

I tried the following:

```
func testSettings() {
        XCUIDevice().siriService.activate(voiceRecognitionText: "Open Settings")
        sleep(2)
        XCUIDevice().siriService.activate(voiceRecognitionText: "General")
    }

}
```

But I'm getting this:

[image]

Any of you knows if a way to tap on buttons using siriService?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

There is not way you can tell Siri to interact directly with components but you can tell it to go directly to the General settings with the following code

```
XCUIDevice().siriService.activate(voiceRecognitionText: "Go to the general settings")
```